# Can I use same param name multiple times in the URL for codeigniter-restserver?

Tags: codeigniter-restserver

http://example.com/api/transfer/transfers/code/456/code/234

When using $this->get('code') on a url like above I expect the REST library to return an array or a list of the codes.

Instead it returns the last one.

Is there a way to return both values in a list, or is there another recommandation for formating the URL.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been long since you posted the question. However it could help other people looking for the same thing.

Assuming that `transfer` is your controller and `transfers` is the function, another way to format your url could be:

http://example.com/api/transfer/transfers?code[]=456&code[]=234

This was you perform `$this->get('code')` you'll get an array back.

If you are creating the url via code then you may use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php). It handles the necessary escaping. It means it will replace `[` for `%5B` and `]` for `%5D`, in this case.

The code would be like:

```
$codes = array(456, 234); 
$query = http_build_query(array('code' => $data));
$url = 'http://example.com/api/transfer/transfers?' . $query;
```

Comment: In this case you might as well use code/456||234 and always do an explode on || (not tested). Thx